# AppendToPath file for MacPorts perl 5.12.3 on MacOSX SnowLeopard

Tags: perl, macports

I am trying to install html2latex on my MacBook Pro. I use the MacPorts perl, v. 5.12.3. When I install the HTML/Latex.pm module, it is installed to

```
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3
```

but perl 5.12.3 doesn't seem too find it. When I run html2latex I get the error:

```
jrmMac 6: html2latex workflow-in-r.html
Can't locate HTML/Latex.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0 .) at /Users/jrminter/bin/html2latex line 81.
```

but note the output of perl -v from the same shell

```
jrmMac 8: perl -v
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for darwin-multi-2level
```

In my web searches, people usually add this directory to the appropriate AppendToPath file. I can's seem to find one in /opt/local. The perl supplied with MaxOSX has files for other versions in:

```
/Library/Perl/5.10.0/AppendToPath
/Library/Perl/5.8.9/AppendToPath
```

Should I just cheat and add it to the 5.10.0 AppendToPath file? I'm not wild about this idea. Why would latex2hml run from my shell get a different perl? I am (obviously) confused... and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem natural that the path is added to @INC when you install the module, but perhaps something went wrong. This seems to be a helpful link:

http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/perl_inc.html